# How to change the remote repository for a git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I've created a git repository with a submodule in it. I'm able to tell the submodule itself to change its remote repository path, but I'm not sure how to tell the parent repository how to change the remote repository path for the submodule.

I wouldn't be surprised if I'm somewhat out of luck and have to do things manually, as even deleting submodules isn't easy.

Comment: Note: Git 2.25 (Q1 2020) comes with [a new command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914135/6309)": `git submodule set-url [--] <path> <newurl>`

Comment: There's an answer for that [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914135/442022).  Please upvote it!

Answer (score 1287):

You should just be able to edit the `.gitmodules` file to update the URL and then run `git submodule sync --recursive` to reflect that change to the superproject and your working copy.

Then you need to go to the `.git/modules/path_to_submodule` dir and change its config file to update git path.

If repo history is different then you need to checkout new branch manually:

```
git submodule sync --recursive
cd <submodule_dir> 

git fetch
git checkout origin/master
git branch master -f
git checkout master
```

Comment: What affect should git submodule sync have? Am I doing it incorrectly in http://gist.github.com/120723 , or am I incorrect in expecting .git/config to be changed by git submodule sync?

Comment: This doesn't seem to update .git/config, at least in 1.7.1 or 1.7.3.

Comment: does this update the submodule url configuration for the previous commits also? ex if i checkout a older commit, will it point to new submodule urls?

Comment: Use `git submodule foreach -q git config remote.origin.url` to see "actual" submodule urls

Comment: @VonC and so it possible to have more than one remote git repo for a submodule? if so how do i do it?

Comment: @abbood not that I know of. Each submodule is associated with one, and only one, git repo.

Comment: It didn't update `.git/config` for me using git 2.1.0. I had to update both `.gitmodules` and `.git/config` manually before running a `git submodule sync --recursive` to have my submodule remote be updated.

Comment: How do I then commit this change in the .gitmodules file? what happens if I checkout a branch/commit earlier than this change? What happens if the old repo and the new repo aren't exactly the same? What will I have in the .git of the submodule? in the working directory of the submodule?

Comment: You can add multiple remotes from inside a subrepo using TortoiseGit so you must be able to do it on the command line. Those extra remotes are local-only, they won't get pushed with the rest of the settings. The extra remotes information ends up in the parent repo's `.git\modules\submodules\name_of_submodule\config` file.

Comment: I had to 'touch' the .gitmodule file to make this work correctly.

Comment: I don't recommend this approach if the path is also changing, as it will leave stale references to the old submodule path inside .git that are difficult/impossible to clean up manually. It's cleaner to run `git submodule deinit modulename` followed by `git submodule init git@server/path/to/repo.git modulename`.

Comment: This appears to be missing the key step of `git submodule update --init --recursive --remote` which actually changes the repository to the new remote

Comment: Since this is the highest-voted answer, it should probably be updated; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914135/5666171)

Comment: None of these worked for me. I had to `cd mymodulename` then `git remote --set-url origin <url>`

Comment: In case you are in a "linked working tree" (attached worktree), the config file is not in `.git/modules/path_to_submodule` , but in `path_to_main_working_tree/.git/worktrees/worktree_name/modules/path_to_submodule`.

Answer (score 297):

With Git 2.25 (Q1 2020), you can **modify** it.
See "[Git submodule url changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59364554/6309)" and the new command

```
git submodule set-url [--] <path> <newurl>
```

(On the `--` separator, see "[double hyphen as a signal to stop option interpretation and treat all following arguments literally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309)")

**WARNING**: [Hi-Angel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2388257/hi-angel) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913701/how-to-change-the-remote-repository-for-a-git-submodule/914135?noredirect=1#comment118169982_914135) (tested even with Git 2.31.1):

> One should be careful with `git submodule set-url` because it has a bug:
>
> If, inside your `.gitmodules` file, the path looks like this `some-path`, and then you execute a:
>
> ```
> # Usually causes unexpected behavior
> git submodule set-url some-path/ new-url
> ```
>
> **(note the trailing slash `/` in `some-path/`)**, then, instead of modifying existing submodule, the command will *add* another one. Instead run:
>
> ```
> # Good
> git submodule set-url some-path new-url
> ```

---

Original answer (May 2009, fourteen years ago)

Actually, a patch [has been submitted in April 2009](https://public-inbox.org/git/526944450904080004r1249d1b8j4a44472d72502b9c@mail.gmail.com/) to clarify `gitmodule` role.

So now the [gitmodule documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) does not yet include:

> The `.gitmodules` file, located in the top-level directory of a git working tree, is a text file with a syntax matching the requirements -of linkgit:git-config[4](https://public-inbox.org/git/526944450904080004r1249d1b8j4a44472d72502b9c@mail.gmail.com/).
> [NEW]:
> As this file is managed by Git, it tracks the +records of a project's submodules.
> Information stored in this file is used as a hint to prime the authoritative version of the record stored in the project configuration file.
> User specific record changes (e.g. to account for differences in submodule URLs due to networking situations) should be made to the configuration file, **while record changes to be propagated (e.g. +due to a relocation of the submodule source) should be made to this file.**

That pretty much confirm [Jim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913701/changing-remote-repository-for-a-git-submodule/914090#914090).

---

If you follow this [git submodule tutorial](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitSubmoduleTutorial), you see you need a "`git submodule init`" to add the submodule repository URLs to .git/config.

"`git submodule sync`" has [been added in August 2008](https://public-inbox.org/git/23327a679798d19dc52a27c55a58c5b8c9ebe945.1219598198.git.davvid@gmail.com/) precisely to make that task easier when URL changes (especially if the number of submodules is important).
The associate script with that command is straightforward enough:

```
module_list "$@" |
while read mode sha1 stage path
do
    name=$(module_name "$path")
    url=$(git config -f .gitmodules --get submodule."$name".url)
    if test -e "$path"/.git
    then
    (
        unset GIT_DIR
        cd "$path"
        remote=$(get_default_remote)
        say "Synchronizing submodule url for '$name'"
        git config remote."$remote".url "$url"
    )
    fi
done
```

The goal remains:  **`git config remote."$remote".url "$url"`**

---

Note:

Git 2.40 (Q1 2023) clarifies `git config remote.<remote>.url`:

See [commit d390e08](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d390e08076b4486b603f0c8496cc09a5eba4106b) (07 Feb 2023) by [Calvin Wan (`CalvinWan0101`)](https://github.com/CalvinWan0101).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 59397e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/59397e9b7e36a1c22196a64bd866224c85c258b6), 15 Feb 2023)</sup>

> ### [`Documentation`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d390e08076b4486b603f0c8496cc09a5eba4106b): clarify multiple `pushurls` vs `urls`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Calvin Wan</sup>

> In a remote with multiple configured URLs, [`git remote -v`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d390e08076b4486b603f0c8496cc09a5eba4106b/Documentation/git-remote.txt#L35)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt--v))</sup> shows the correct url that fetch uses.
>
> However, [`git config remote.<remote>.url`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d390e08076b4486b603f0c8496cc09a5eba4106b/Documentation/git-config.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config))</sup> **returns the last defined url instead**.
>
> This discrepancy can cause confusion for users with a remote defined as such, since any url defined after the first essentially acts as a `pushurl`.
>
> Add documentation to clarify how fetch interacts with multiple urls and how push interacts with multiple pushurls and urls.

`urls-remotes` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d390e08076b4486b603f0c8496cc09a5eba4106b/Documentation/urls-remotes.txt#L36-L38):

> The `<pushurl>` is used for pushes only.
>
> It is optional and defaults
> to `<URL>`.
>
> Pushing to a remote affects all defined pushurls or to all
> defined urls if no pushurls are defined.
> Fetch, however, will only
> fetch from the first defined url if muliple urls are defined.

---

Git 2.44 (Q1 2024), [batch 10](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b50a608ba20348cb3dfc16a696816d51780e3f0f), tightens URL checks fsck makes in a URL recorded for submodules.

So when you change the URL, the URL validity check is now more robust.

See [commit 8430b43](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8430b438f628f2f0df08622a550e750158167f28), [commit 7e2fc39](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7e2fc39d8c02048e9dddcba1b1b6786a8088a1a8), [commit 6af2c4a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6af2c4ad45083df07b81ebb2c449f97f0bb69315), [commit 13320ff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13320ff610b4083341175c4f8e636a1bc52145f5) (18 Jan 2024) by [Victoria Dye (`vdye`)](https://github.com/vdye).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 76bd129](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76bd1294d8ed21d2d7e8d35220a0e820969c5ee8), 26 Jan 2024)</sup>

> ### [`submodule-config.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8430b438f628f2f0df08622a550e750158167f28): strengthen URL fsck check
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Victoria Dye</sup>

> Update the validation of "curl URL" submodule URLs (i.e.
> those that specify an "http[s]" or "ftp[s]" protocol) in '`check_submodule_url()`' to catch more invalid URLs.
> The existing validation using '`credential_from_url_gently()`' parses certain URLs incorrectly, leading to invalid submodule URLs passing '[`git fsck`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8430b438f628f2f0df08622a550e750158167f28/Documentation/git-fsck.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck))</sup> checks.
> Conversely, '`url_normalize()`' - used to validate remote URLs in '`remote_get()`' - correctly identifies the invalid URLs missed by '`credential_from_url_gently()`'.
>
> To catch more invalid cases, replace '`credential_from_url_gently()`' with '`url_normalize()`' followed by a '`url_decode()`' and a check for newlines (mirroring '`check_url_component()`' in the '`credential_from_url_gently()`' validation).

Comment: I wanted to change the submodule's URL only on this machine. From the parent project I could modify the record in `.git/config` by doing: `git config submodule."$submodule_name".url "$new_url"
` which is [also described here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/928539/99777).

Comment: What does the optional double dashes in `git submodule set-url [--] <path> <newurl>` do?

Comment: @jeverling They help separate options from parameters: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309

Comment: Note that for Ubuntu users with an older version git you can use this PPA to update: https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: This should be the preferred answer now. One simple command for everything.

Comment: What does `[--]` mean? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Harry It separates options from file parameters. I have documented the double-hyphen syntax in 2009, twelve years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309

Comment: I would also be interested to know what the `[--]` mean

Comment: @M.Ionut That is what I describe/explain in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309

Comment: I think that ` -- ` allows you to have a preceding `-` or `--` in the arguments that follow and not have them interpreted as options. Chances are, if you are doing direct work on the command line, you won't need this because you are probably not a maniac who puts `-` or `--` at the beginning of things. But it might happen for some reason and so for more robust scripts, you can use the ` -- ` to signal to the command line parser to no longer interpret dashes specially. It's confusing until you think of it as a script-writing tool, mainly.

Comment: @DanielRussell Good point. I really like to use `--`, precisely to *not* worry about what follows. Everything before are options, everything after, aguments.

Answer (score 203):

These commands will do the work on command prompt without altering any files on local repository

```
git config --file=.gitmodules submodule.Submod.url https://github.com/username/ABC.git
git config --file=.gitmodules submodule.Submod.branch Development
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init --recursive --remote
```

Please look at the blog for screenshots: [Changing GIT submodules URL/Branch to other URL/branch of same repository](http://pa1gitsolutions.blogspot.ca/2015/07/changing-git-submodules-urlbranch-to.html)

Comment: This worked but I had to remember to push the changes to the remote. `git add .gitmodules` `git commit -m "modified submodule URL"` `git push origin master`

Comment: Well, that created a terrible mess for me. Commands went down quietly,  but the actual submodule repository still thinks its remote is the old one (the old URL). Maybe these commands should be accompanied with other commands within the submodule's repository?

Comment: The last command is a bit extreme... If you have submodules with submodules inside, this will remotely update the sub-submodules as well, which is unlikely what you need.

Comment: Note that you need replace Submod with name of your submodule!

Comment: This is less risky than going into your .gitmodules file manually. thx 

Comment: reply for other question about submodule url https://stackoverflow.com/a/42035018/205355  helpful description for command semantic

Answer (score 167):

In simple terms, you just need to edit the .gitmodules file, then resync and update:

Edit the file, either via a git command or directly:

```
git config --file=.gitmodules -e
```

or just:

```
vim .gitmodules
```

then resync and update:

```
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init --recursive --remote
```

Comment: `git submodule update --init` worked for me, `--remote` seems to tie it to the HEAD of the remote repo.

Answer (score 89):

What worked for me (on Windows, using git version 1.8.3.msysgit.0):

- Update .gitmodules with the URL to the new repository
- Remove the corresponding line from the ".git/config" file
- Delete the corresponding directory in the ".git/modules/external" directory (".git/modules" for recent git versions)
- Delete the checked out submodule directory itself (unsure if this is necessary)
- Run `git submodule init` and `git submodule update`
- Make sure the checked out submodule is at the correct commit, and commit that, since it's likely that the hash will be different

After doing all that, everything is in the state I would expect. I imagine other users of the repository will have similar pain when they come to update though - it would be wise to explain these steps in your commit message!

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This is the only one that worked for me after I had already run a `git submodule update`. Following the other answers wouldn't change what was in the `./git/modules/external` dir so attempting to update would result in it still pulling the incorrect url.

Comment: this seems to be a bit dangerous, and I'm not sure it preserves the history of the previous submodule. If, for instance, you want to check out an old commit or branch of your main-repository (the one containing the submodule) I'm not sure it will know to pull the OLD submodule attached and related to that old commit of the main.

Comment: No, it almost certainly won't know - you'll have to do all the steps after the first one again. This is just what I found worked for nuking the current state of the submodule. I don't know if the state of things has changed since I wrote this, mind :)

Comment: @MottiShneor that seems dangerous indeed if you need to keep the previous submodule history, though I'm not sure about it. In my case it's the only solution that worked, what I wanted was basically replace the original submodule with my own fork

Comment: Followed these steps and found that the "Delete the checked out submodule directory itself (unsure if this is necessary)" is necessary otherwise you will encounter "fatal: Not a git repository:  ..." when running git submodule update

Answer (score 15):

Just edit your **.git/config** file. For example; if you have a *"common"* submodule you can do this in the super-module:

```
git config submodule.common.url /data/my_local_common
```

Comment: This is only the best way if you are trying to change the URL for a one time use, not permanently in the super project. E.g. you want to clone submodules from local copies on disk.

Answer (score 3):

`git config --file=.gitmodules -e` opens the default editor in which you can update the path

Answer (score -2):

A brute force approach:

- update the `.gitmodules` file in the supermodule to point to the new submodule url,
- add and commit the changes to `supermodule/.gitmodules`,
- make a new clone of the supermodule somewhere else on your computer (making sure that the latest changes to the `.gitmodules` file are reflected in the clone),
- change your working directory to the new clone of the supermodule,
- run `git submodule update --init --remote path-to-submodule` on the submodule,

et voilà! The submodule in the new clone of the supermodule is properly configured!