# git: change origin of cloned submodule

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I created a project `submodule` and put it up on Github.

I created another project, `supermodule`, and then did this:

```
cd supermodule
git init
mkdir lib
git clone git://github.com/tandu/submodule lib/submodule
git submodule add ./lib/submodule lib/submodule
```

This worked fine, but on the website, it can't find the link to the submodule when viewing the files (in fact it just says "Loading Commit data" forever).  The submodule folder itself has the correct `origin`.

Apparently, what I should have done was

```
...
mkdir lib
git submodule add git://github.com/tandu/submodule lib
```

...but it's too late for that now.  How can I have the submodule in this project correctly point to `origin`?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This apparently is very much dependent on the version of git you are using.

1. If present, change the `url` entry in the `[submodule "<dirname>"]` section of the `.gitmodules` file.
2. If present, change the `url` entry in the `[submodule "<dirname>"]` section of the `.git/config` file.
3. Change the `url` in the configuration of the submodule itself. The location of the `config` file is version dependent. Older versions had it in `<dirname>/.git/config`, newer ones in `.git/modules/<dirname>/config`. However, you can always use below command:

```
cd <dirname>
git config remote.origin.url <new_url>
```

Comment: with the current version of git (2.1.0), doing `git submodule sync --recursive` was enough for me to update to submodule `origin` remote.

Answer (score 20):

In other question I found [answer for more modern Git version (2.25)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914135/8212196)

`git submodule [--quiet] set-url [--] <path> <newurl>`

Let's assume that you have submodule in directory `external/foo-lib` which origins is `https://github.com/example-user/foo-lib.git` and you want to change it to yours fork `https://github.com/your-account/foo-lib.git` then in root directory of git project type:

`git submodule set-url external/foo-lib https://github.com/your-account/foo-lib.git`