# Why is Teamcity not able to pull down git submodule

Tags: git, github, teamcity, git-submodules

I have a git project that has a submodule.  This submodule is used in two repositories that are both being built on a Teamcity server.  Teamcity is able to build the first project but the the second project has the following error (details have been qouted out to protect the guilty)

> Error collecting changes for VCS repository 'TirePlotter'
>   Collecting changes failed: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.CorruptObjectException: Object 'git hash here' is corrupt: 'git fetch' command failed.
>   stderr: 'project submodule name url': 'project submodule name url'/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found 
>   « Hide stacktrace
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException: Error collecting changes for VCS repository 'TirePlotter' 
>   Collecting changes failed: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.CorruptObjectException: Object 'git hash here' is corrupt: 'git fetch' command failed. 
>   stderr: 'project submodule name url': 'project submodule name url'/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.OperationContext.wrapException(OperationContext.java:139) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.collectChanges(GitVcsSupport.java:142) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.CollectRepositoryChangesByCheckoutRulesAdapter.collectChanges(CollectRepositoryChangesByCheckoutRulesAdapter.java:5)
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.CollectChangesBetweenRepositoriesAdapter.collectChanges(CollectChangesBetweenRepositoriesAdapter.java:6)
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges$CollectChangesInSingleRepository.perform(LoadChanges.java:2) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.perform(LoadChanges.java:60) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChangesForCheckoutRules(LoadChanges.java:46) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChanges(LoadChanges.java:20) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.run(LoadChanges.java:105) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.VcsRootChangesLoader._loadChanges(VcsRootChangesLoader.java:31) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.VcsRootChangesLoader.loadChanges(VcsRootChangesLoader.java:43) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesLoaderImpl.doLoadChanges(VcsChangesLoaderImpl.java:94) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesLoaderImpl.loadChangesNoLocking(VcsChangesLoaderImpl.java:16) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesLoaderImpl.loadChanges(VcsChangesLoaderImpl.java:133) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsManagerImpl.loadChanges(VcsManagerImpl.java:604) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.auth.SecuredVcsManager.loadChanges(SecuredVcsManager.java:72) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.VcsModificationChecker$1.run(VcsModificationChecker.java:11) 
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
>   Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.CorruptObjectException: Object 'Git hash here' is corrupt: 'git fetch' command failed. 
>   stderr: 'project submodule name url': 'project submodule name url'/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.SubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.movedToEntry(SubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.java:187)
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.DirectSubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.next(DirectSubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.java:86)
>   at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.AbstractTreeIterator.skip(AbstractTreeIterator.java:628) 
>   at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.skipEntriesEqual(TreeWalk.java:944) 
>   at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.next(TreeWalk.java:554) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.ModificationDataRevWalk.getCommitChanges(ModificationDataRevWalk.java:152) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.ModificationDataRevWalk.createModificationData(ModificationDataRevWalk.java:91) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.getModifications(GitVcsSupport.java:164) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.collectChanges(GitVcsSupport.java:140) 
>   ... 21 more 
>   Caused by: jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException: 'git fetch' command failed. 
>   stderr: 'project submodule name url': 'project submodule name url'/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.CommandLineUtil.getCommandLineError(CommandLineUtil.java:44) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.FetchCommandImpl.fetchInSeparateProcess(FetchCommandImpl.java:132) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.FetchCommandImpl.fetch(FetchCommandImpl.java:70) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.fetch(GitVcsSupport.java:716) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.TeamCitySubmoduleResolver.fetch(TeamCitySubmoduleResolver.java:79) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.SubmoduleResolver.getSubmoduleCommit(SubmoduleResolver.java:76) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.SubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.getSubmoduleCommit(SubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.java:224)
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.SubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.movedToEntry(SubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.java:174)
>   ... 29 more 
>   org.eclipse.jgit.errors.CorruptObjectException: Object 'git hash here' is corrupt: 'git fetch' command failed. 
>   stderr: 'project submodule name url': 'project submodule name url'/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.SubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.movedToEntry(SubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.java:187)
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.DirectSubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.next(DirectSubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.java:86)
>   at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.AbstractTreeIterator.skip(AbstractTreeIterator.java:628) 
>   at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.skipEntriesEqual(TreeWalk.java:944) 
>   at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.next(TreeWalk.java:554) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.ModificationDataRevWalk.getCommitChanges(ModificationDataRevWalk.java:152) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.ModificationDataRevWalk.createModificationData(ModificationDataRevWalk.java:91) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.getModifications(GitVcsSupport.java:164) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.collectChanges(GitVcsSupport.java:140) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.CollectRepositoryChangesByCheckoutRulesAdapter.collectChanges(CollectRepositoryChangesByCheckoutRulesAdapter.java:5)
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.CollectChangesBetweenRepositoriesAdapter.collectChanges(CollectChangesBetweenRepositoriesAdapter.java:6)
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges$CollectChangesInSingleRepository.perform(LoadChanges.java:2) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.perform(LoadChanges.java:60) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChangesForCheckoutRules(LoadChanges.java:46) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChanges(LoadChanges.java:20) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.run(LoadChanges.java:105) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.VcsRootChangesLoader._loadChanges(VcsRootChangesLoader.java:31) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.VcsRootChangesLoader.loadChanges(VcsRootChangesLoader.java:43) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesLoaderImpl.doLoadChanges(VcsChangesLoaderImpl.java:94) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesLoaderImpl.loadChangesNoLocking(VcsChangesLoaderImpl.java:16) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesLoaderImpl.loadChanges(VcsChangesLoaderImpl.java:133) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsManagerImpl.loadChanges(VcsManagerImpl.java:604) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.auth.SecuredVcsManager.loadChanges(SecuredVcsManager.java:72) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.VcsModificationChecker$1.run(VcsModificationChecker.java:11) 
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
>   Caused by: jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException: 'git fetch' command failed. 
>   stderr: https://engdeveloper@github.com/rcrenterprises/RCR.Simulation: https://engdeveloper@github.com/rcrenterprises/RCR.Simulation/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.CommandLineUtil.getCommandLineError(CommandLineUtil.java:44) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.FetchCommandImpl.fetchInSeparateProcess(FetchCommandImpl.java:132) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.FetchCommandImpl.fetch(FetchCommandImpl.java:70) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.fetch(GitVcsSupport.java:716) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.TeamCitySubmoduleResolver.fetch(TeamCitySubmoduleResolver.java:79) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.SubmoduleResolver.getSubmoduleCommit(SubmoduleResolver.java:76) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.SubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.getSubmoduleCommit(SubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.java:224)
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.SubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.movedToEntry(SubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.java:174)
>   ... 29 more 
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.VcsException: 'git fetch' command failed. 
>   stderr: 'project submodule name url': 'project submodule name url'/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.CommandLineUtil.getCommandLineError(CommandLineUtil.java:44) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.FetchCommandImpl.fetchInSeparateProcess(FetchCommandImpl.java:132) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.FetchCommandImpl.fetch(FetchCommandImpl.java:70) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.fetch(GitVcsSupport.java:716) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.TeamCitySubmoduleResolver.fetch(TeamCitySubmoduleResolver.java:79) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.SubmoduleResolver.getSubmoduleCommit(SubmoduleResolver.java:76) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.SubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.getSubmoduleCommit(SubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.java:224)
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.SubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.movedToEntry(SubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.java:174)
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.submodules.DirectSubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.next(DirectSubmoduleAwareTreeIterator.java:86)
>   at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.AbstractTreeIterator.skip(AbstractTreeIterator.java:628) 
>   at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.skipEntriesEqual(TreeWalk.java:944) 
>   at org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk.next(TreeWalk.java:554) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.ModificationDataRevWalk.getCommitChanges(ModificationDataRevWalk.java:152) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.ModificationDataRevWalk.createModificationData(ModificationDataRevWalk.java:91) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.getModifications(GitVcsSupport.java:164) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.collectChanges(GitVcsSupport.java:140) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.CollectRepositoryChangesByCheckoutRulesAdapter.collectChanges(CollectRepositoryChangesByCheckoutRulesAdapter.java:5)
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.CollectChangesBetweenRepositoriesAdapter.collectChanges(CollectChangesBetweenRepositoriesAdapter.java:6)
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges$CollectChangesInSingleRepository.perform(LoadChanges.java:2) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.perform(LoadChanges.java:60) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChangesForCheckoutRules(LoadChanges.java:46) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.collectChanges(LoadChanges.java:20) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.LoadChanges.run(LoadChanges.java:105) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.VcsRootChangesLoader._loadChanges(VcsRootChangesLoader.java:31) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.VcsRootChangesLoader.loadChanges(VcsRootChangesLoader.java:43) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesLoaderImpl.doLoadChanges(VcsChangesLoaderImpl.java:94) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesLoaderImpl.loadChangesNoLocking(VcsChangesLoaderImpl.java:16) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsChangesLoaderImpl.loadChanges(VcsChangesLoaderImpl.java:133) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsManagerImpl.loadChanges(VcsManagerImpl.java:604) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.auth.SecuredVcsManager.loadChanges(SecuredVcsManager.java:72) 
>   at jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.VcsModificationChecker$1.run(VcsModificationChecker.java:11) 
>   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I have tried to rebuild it with a clean directory and verified that the git repository is fine.  Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?  Side note: the repositories are on github if that helps anyone.

Answer (score 11):

I've just had this same problem - in my case, we had TeamCity configured to use HTTPS and username/password auth when checking out Github repositories, but the .gitmodules file contained the SSH URL (`git@github.com:MyCompany/Submodule.git`) of the submodule repository.

I fixed it by editing `.gitmodules` and changing the URL to https://github.com/MyCompany/Submodule.git.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `.git` to your submodule link: `https://engdeveloper@github.com/rcrenterprises/RCR.Simulation.git` instead of `https://engdeveloper@github.com/rcrenterprises/RCR.Simulation`.

Comment: Found this link to change the gitmodules file, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913701/changing-remote-repository-for-a-git-submodule but it is still failing with this commang Failed to collect changes, error: Error collecting changes for VCS repository 'TIrePlotter'
Collecting changes failed: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.CorruptObjectException: Repository 'http://engdeveloper@github.com/rcrenterprises/TirePlotter.git' has submodule in commit '0fa7a5b84bd6037d0e063ad3ad6b47fccabbbbd2' at path 'RCR.Simulation', but has no entry for this path in .gitmodules configuration.

Comment: It seems like there is no entry in .gitmodules for subrepository at path RCS.Sumulation, I'd try to add it.

Comment: contents of .gitmodules on server [submodule "RCR.Simulation"]
 path = RCR.Simulation
 url = https://github.com/rcrenterprises/RCR.Simulation.git

Comment: I have the same issue, but this is not the solution. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-36303

Answer (score 1):

We have the same problem after subtree merge:
: VCS Root: DPPDev: Commit 'c77771ccd2f5b23aae5eafc3d4bf4cb6e6d6fec4' is not found in repository.

Added "empty" commit for fix - then success

Comment: This worked for me.  Specifically, I had to add a commit to the submodule's repo, not the repo where the submodule is used..