# How do I replace a git submodule with another repo?

Tags: git, git-submodules

How do I replace a git submodule with a different git repo?

Specifically, I have a submodule:

- located at `./ExternalFrameworks/TestFramework` that points to a git repo `git@github.com:userA/TestFramework.git`
- I'd like it to now point to `git@github.com:userB/TestFramework.git`.

The problem is that when I delete the submodule with the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule), then re-add it using the command

```
git submodule add git@github.com:userB/TestFramework.git
```

I get this error:

```
A git directory for 'ExternalFrameworks/TestFramework' is found locally with remote(s):
  origin    git@github.com:userA/TestFramework.git
If you want to reuse this local git directory instead of cloning again from
  git@github.com:userB/TestFramework.git
use the '--force' option. If the local git directory is not the correct repo
or you are unsure what this means choose another name with the '--name' option.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing remote repository for a git submodule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913701/changing-remote-repository-for-a-git-submodule)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

If the location (URL) of the submodule has changed, then you can simply:

1. Modify the `.gitmodules` file in the repo root to use the new URL.
2. Delete the submodule folder in the repo `rm -rf .git/modules/<submodule>`.
3. Delete the submodule folder in the working directory `rm -rf <submodule>`.
4. Run `git submodule sync`.
5. Run `git submodule update`.

More complete info can be found elsewhere:

- [Changing remote repository for a git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913701/changing-remote-repository-for-a-git-submodule)

Comment: Also worth noting: when another user (who had already inited the submodule) gets your update, they will also have to do the "git submodule sync" one time before the new submodule will work for them.

Comment: This did not work for me. My submodule still pointed to the old URL after this. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Arne Maybe your submodule was never initialized properly.  I had to `rm -rf .git/modules/<submodule>` before it worked for me.

Comment: @DavidBraun I have the same problem as @Arne though doing `git submodule sync` after `rm -rf .git/modules/<submodule>` gives `fatal: Not a git repository: ../.git/modules/<submodule>`. Any tips? I initially created the submodule via `git submodule add https://<submodule-url>` as per the git docs...

Comment: @acannon828 I don't have any tips; I'm too far away from the problem now.  Best of luck.

Comment: @acannon828 git is trying to find an inexistent path (`.git/modules/<submodule>.`). Remove the corresponding path and update: `rm -rf <submodule> && git submodule update`

Comment: Afterwards I had to cd to the module's directory, git checkout the branch I want, then git pull.

Comment: This is good only if the only thing changed is the URL from which you bring your submodule repository. However the original question was about replacing the git repository of the submodule. For example, I used a github project as my submodule. I found a bug there, but the repo is not active. So I have to fork it, and apply the fix on my own fork - which is now a different repository. Your method won't work for me,

Comment: I get `error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object 6ed9043bcb3bf7269bba3e60f2bb59b403a7cb13` and `Fetched in submodule path 'app/code/Magenerds/PageDesigner', but it did not contain 6ed9043bcb3bf7269bba3e60f2bb59b403a7cb13. Direct fetching of that commit failed.`

Comment: I had to run `git submodule update --remote` for this to work.

Answer (score 37):

First, delete the current submodule with the method already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260748/how-do-i-remove-a-git-submodule), which I'm including for convenience:

- Delete the relevant section from the `.gitmodules` file
- Delete the relevant section from `.git/config`
- Run `git rm --cached path_to_submodule` (no trailing slash)
- Commit and delete the now untracked submodule files

Now, add the new submodule with the `--name` flag.  This will give git an alternate name to reference in `.git/config` for the submodule, to deconflict with the submodule that was there historically, which you still want to work in your prior history.

So type:

```
git submodule add --name UpdatedTestFramework git@github.com:userB/TestFramework.git
```

and you'll get the submodule loaded at the path you expect.

Comment: While this way does work, it's not nearly as clean as Tim's method.

Comment: This worked for me but I also had to delete `.git/modules/<path_to_submodule>`.

Comment: Appreciate the reference to `--name`. I wasn't aware of the issues surrounding this, and I wasn't able to replace a submodule until I made use of this option (thanks to your answer).

Comment: This eneded up being the only method that worked for me, however I wanted to keep the same directory name. It did checkout correct path and make the module name the desired name but the working directory name was the new repo name. So If you want the same name you need to also specify that at the end of the url like so: 

`git submodule add --name old-name-to-keep git@github.com:userB/new-repository.git old-name-to-keep`

Answer (score 11):

These commands will do the work on command prompt without altering any files on local repository.

```
git config --file=.gitmodules submodule.Submod.url https://github.com/username/ABC.git
git config --file=.gitmodules submodule.Submod.branch Dev
git submodule sync
git submodule update --init --recursive --remote
```

Comment: The commands change the `.gitmodules` file

Answer (score 5):

What fixed this for me was in the root of your git repo (not the submodule), run

```
rm -rf .git/modules/yourmodule
```

Then you should be able to add as normal.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way that I found is this:

```
git rm -rf [submodule_dir]
git submodule add --name new_[submodule_name] [new_submodule_url] [submodule_dir]
```

I didn't like the idea to modify my `.gitmodules` manually. I also wrote [a little blogpost](http://der-zyklop.de/blog/git-new-submodule-url) about it.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the remote URL **only for this clone**:

```sh
git config submodule."$submodule_name".url "$new_url"
```

This won't affect the `.gitmodules` file in the parent project, so it won't be propagated to other developers.

This is described as "user specific record changes" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914135/99777).

***Do not*** run `git submodule sync` as that will reset to the default URL again.