# Git submodule troubles - changing underlying repo address

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project where I added a git submodule to a fork of a repo that is out of date. Rather than pointing to that fork, I decided to change the submodule reference to point to the original repo instead.

I edited the `.gitmodules` file to reflect the new reference and ran `git submodule init` and `git submodule update --recursive` however there is no effect, am I missing a step here?

Comment: You may need to manually change the url in `.git/config` of your submodule.

Comment: Great find! See my comments on the @VonC's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

[neevek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/668963/neevek) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15215278/git-submodule-troubles-changing-underlying-repo-address#comment21446637_15215278) `.git/config`, and the documentation of [`git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config.html) confirms:

submodule..path
submodule..url
submodule..update

> The path within this project, URL, and the updating strategy for a submodule.
>   These variables are initially populated by `git submodule init`; **edit them to override the URL and other values found in the `.gitmodules` file**.

So:

- changing the values in the `.gitmodules` alone isn't enough (the url in the `.git/config` will have precedence).
- [`git submodule init`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule), as the documentation mentions, **does not alter existing information in `.git/config`** (and that explains why your commands didn't have any visible effect).
  You can then customize the submodule clone URLs in `.git/config` for your local setup and proceed to `git submodule update`.

I personally find this url duplication a bit confusing...

Comment: I tried this approach, and after updating the `config` URL to the original repo, I am still not able to get `git submodule update` to work. Really nice find though.

Comment: What's worse is I followed the steps here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404704/how-do-i-replace-a-git-submodule-with-another-repo and `git submodule sync` doesn't work either. Git is just acting like a total git today (sorry couldn't help myself)