# Git add all repositories under a certain path as submodules recursively

Tags: git

How can I add all sub-repositories inside a just-initialized git repository as submodules?

I have two repositories I've been tracking separately, now I want to take those into a larger project, but still keep their respective origins.

I currently just did `git init`.

Also, if possible:

- Without removing any directories temporarily
- Without using a bash script

Comment: Perhaps this question should be migrated to Unix&Linux ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec git submodule add ./{} \;
```

That should fail for regular folders, and succeed for folders which are nested git repo within your main repo you just initialized.

Once added, you will need to commit in your main repo, in order to record all the [gitlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309) you just created (with `submodule add`).

Note that you would still have [to update the url of those submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14405542/6309) you just added (because their current url would be their own folder)