# How to push a modification on a git submodule without giving username/password

Tags: git, git-submodules, public-key

I'm currently trying  to deal with git submodules and I'm having trouble when I want to push modifications on children repository.

I get the following error:

```
fatal: remote error: 
  You can't push to git://github.com/yllieth/ui.git
  Use https://github.com/yllieth/ui.git
```

Indeed, it's working fine if I change my remote configuration to use HTTPS instead of ssh public key. But I would like to avoid giving my github's username/password.

Is anyone knows some configuration tips or something else to be able to push to a submodule using my public key ?

Comment: See this question "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343068/is-there-a-way-to-skip-password-typing-when-using-https-github"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's working fine if I change my remote configuration to use HTTPS instead of ssh public key.

Note that `git://github.com/yllieth/ui.git` is *not* an ssh url.
See "[Which remote URL should I use?](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use)" and "[Changing a remote's URL](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url)":

`git@github.com:username/reponame.git` would.
In your case: `git@github.com:yllieth/ui.git`

So you still can use ssh, but you need to [change the submodule url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14405542/6309).

Comment: My mistake ! It seems I added my submodule with a bad url (`git://` instead of `git@...`. That'll teach me to use my memory rather than copy and paste ;) Thanks to you @VonC