# Modify URL of a nested submodule in git

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I'm working with the latest version of ardupilot firmware.
The goal is to make the ardupilot talking with a companion board using the mavlink protocol.

I started creating a fork of the original ardupilot repository on my github account.

The integration of the companion board would require me to modify also the code of some submodules of the ardupilot repository: PX4Firmware and mavlink.

Therefore, in order to be able to do it, I've forked also the various submodules of ardupilot on my github account.

Then, I've modified the .gitmodules file on my fork of the ardupilot repo, to be sure that the initialization of the submodules uses my forks instead of the original ones. The modification are as follows:

```
[submodule "modules/PX4Firmware"]
path = modules/PX4Firmware
url = git://github.com/MY_GITHUB_ACCOUNT/PX4Firmware.git
[submodule "modules/PX4NuttX"]
path = modules/PX4NuttX
url = git://github.com/MY_GITHUB_ACCOUNT/PX4NuttX.git
[submodule "modules/uavcan"]
path = modules/uavcan
url = git://github.com/MY_GITHUB_ACCOUNT/uavcan.git
[submodule "modules/waf"]
path = modules/waf
url = git://github.com/MY_GITHUB_ACCOUNT/waf.git
[submodule "modules/gbenchmark"]
path = modules/gbenchmark
url = git://github.com/MY_GITHUB_ACCOUNT/benchmark.git
[submodule "modules/mavlink"]
path = modules/mavlink
url = git://github.com/MY_GITHUB_ACCOUNT/mavlink
[submodule "gtest"]
path = modules/gtest
url = git://github.com/MY_GITHUB_ACCOUNT/googletest
```

After this, I realized that I need to modify the code of one submodule of the PX4Firmware as well. Therefore I repeated the same procedure within the PX4Firmware repo:

1. Fork of the sub-sub-module on my github account
2. Modification of the .gitmodules file inside the PX4Firmware repo as follows:

   ```
   [submodule "mavlink/include/mavlink/v1.0"]
   path = mavlink/include/mavlink/v1.0
   url = git://github.com/MY_GITHUB_ACCOUNT/c_library.git
   [submodule "src/modules/uavcan/libuavcan"]
   path = src/modules/uavcan/libuavcan
   url = git://github.com/UAVCAN/libuavcan.git
   [submodule "Tools/genmsg"]
   path = Tools/genmsg
   url = https://github.com/ros/genmsg.git
   [submodule "Tools/gencpp"]
   path = Tools/gencpp
   url = https://github.com/ros/gencpp.git
   [submodule "src/lib/matrix"]
   path = src/lib/matrix
   url = https://github.com/PX4/Matrix.git
   [submodule "src/lib/DriverFramework"]
   path = src/lib/DriverFramework
   url = https://github.com/PX4/DriverFramework.git
   [submodule "src/lib/ecl"]
   path = src/lib/ecl
   url = https://github.com/PX4/ecl.git
   ```

After modifying the files, I run the commands **git submodule sync** and **git submodule update**. I've also commited both .gitmodules files and pushed them to the corresponding master branches.

To see if it worked, I cloned my fork of the ardupilot on a new folder and initialized all the submodules recursively:

```
git clone https://github.com/MY_GITHUB_ACCOUNT/ardupilot.git
cd ardupilot
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Unfortunately it didn't work as expected. While the submodules of my fork of ardupilot seemed to be downloaded from my github, the submodules of the PX4Firmware are still downloaded from the original repos.

Here you can find the output of the **git submodule update --init --recursive** command: https://pastebin.com/ECi4wQEZ

My problem is that I cannot commit on the original repositories, of course, therefore I have to work with forks to keep track of my modifications, as far as I understood.

I've found and tried many asnwers here on stackoverflow:

1. [How do I replace a git submodule with another repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404704/how-do-i-replace-a-git-submodule-with-another-repo/)
2. [Changing remote repository for a git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913701/changing-remote-repository-for-a-git-submodule)

and many others, but none of them worked in my case.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you.

**-------- UPDATE --------**

In the meantime I've found a way to make it working.

I describe the procedure here in case someone needs it or knows a better way to do that:

I started solving the issue about the url of the sub-sub module: make sure that the PX4Firmware repo uses git://github.com/MY_GITHUB_ACCOUNT/c_library.git instead of the original one.

Here is the procedure:

1. Go on the main page of the PX4Firmware repo on my github
2. Modify the .gitmodules file (change of url). **Note:** I've figured out that the git protocol doesn't allow to push, therefore I've used https.
3. Save changes.
4. Clone the PX4Firmware repository on my PC.
5. Initialize the submodules after going the root folder of the PX4Firmware repo, with the command **git submodule update --init --recursive**
6. cd into the submodule folder
7. running the command **git checkout __sha__** where **sha** is the latest commit of my local copy of the sub-sub module.
8. going up one level with **cd..**
9. running the command **git add submodule_folder**
10. git commit and then push

From the main repository (ardupilot) I repeated the same procedure to make sure that the PX4Firmware submodule is the fork on my repository instead of the original one.

I'm sure there is a better way to do this. If you know it, please share.
I also hope this can help somebody else with the same problem.