# Submodule project died, how to import the code?

Tags: git

My project has a particular submodule that, since 2 days is no more live. The authors ha removed the repository at all from github.

I need to know how to remove the submodule without loosing the code.

Actually the submodule is located into

project_root/external_modules/name_of_died_project

I need to keep the code in the same position. I don'r want to pushit  to a separeted NEW repo.

The code of the last commit is actually on my drive.
It's not that I cannot push into a new repo.. i DONT'WANT to do it. 
I simply want to keep the code and handle them as a simple standard subdirectory of the project, without change any path config

Comment: Is the submodule still on your local hard drive?

Comment: Why can't you push it to a new location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The submodule is an individual Git repository itself. That means you can push a copy of it to your own GitHub account. To do so do the following:

Change to the submodule

```
cd path/to/submodule
```

and push everything to your repo on GitHub (or wherever you prefer, simply replace the URL)

```
git push git@github.com:your-username/your-repo.git --all
```

You should see a copy of the repo on your GitHub account.

Afterwards follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14405542/636626) to change the submodule URL in your parent project:

In your main project open the file `.gitmodules`, search for the corresponding submodule block

```
[submodule "path/to/submodule"]
    path = path/to/submodule
    url = https://github.com/dead-account/dead-repo.git
```

and replace the old dead URL with your new one from above. Then run

```
git submodule sync
```

and commit the changes

```
git commit -am "Fixed disappeared submodule upstream"
```

Comment: I edited my question. I must 'import' the code in the same position but NOT  as new repository. Simply I want to add the actual code into the actual 'master' project.... I need to trasnform from a submodule into a 'normal' directory of code