# Transfering repository of project from company to github with submodules

Tags: git, github

We have a project that is hosted in a company owned git server (not github). Since the project is complete and client already paid for it, we want to transfer it to them, and the client is planning to upload it to github (as private).

The project has submodules installed on it.

Do we download the project as zip, delete the .git folder and upload it to github? How about the submodules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Create the new repo in Github.

2- In your local repo change origin:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user/example.git
```

3- Push the repo to your new origin

4- Update the remote repository url for submodules:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60003644/13126940