# Change directory of source files in VS 2012 express

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, github

I have an existing C# project in VS 2012 express that I'd like to add to a repository. I'm very new to source control, so please excuse me if this is a novice question.

I installed GitHub and created a repository, and I'd like this repository to contain the source files in `Visual Studio\Projects\My Project`, i.e. the default source directory for my project. Unfortunately GitHub creates a new folder, so I'd need to copy in the files into that folder every time I change them. Alternatively, I could change the directory that VS saves the source files in to the directory created by GitHub. I've searched around, and I haven't found a way to do this in VS 2012 express. Is this possible? Or is there a better/easier solution I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is:

- initialize a git repo right within your existing VS project: `git init .` (no additional directory created, except for a `.git`)
- Ask "GitHub for Windows" to [scan for existing repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14455249/6309) and find the one you have created.
  (Although you should simply be able to drag&drop the VS project directory to the GitHub for Windows GUI)
- publish it on GitHub (it would create a new public repo on GitHub)