# How to fix a permission denied (publickey) error for a git submodule update in the Github Travis CI build?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, travis-ci

I cannot update the git submodule, with the error:

```
$ git submodule init
Submodule 'build/html' (git@github.com:quadroid/clonejs.git) registered for path 'build/html'
...
$ git submodule update
Cloning into 'build/html'...
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,207.97.227.239' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

But when I do the same tasks locally, everything is OK.

How do I fix this so that the Travis CI build passes and I can still click on the submodule in the repo to direct to it?

Comment: fixed by changing submodule url to git://github.com/quadroid/clonejs.git
But now I can't push this module locally...

Comment: use a [deploy key](https://help.github.com/categories/30/articles) or have a script change the URL only in travis, not on your local

Comment: This article helped me https://awolski.com/sudden-permission-denied-publickey-error-in-travis/ 
In short, you have to disable and enable Travis builds for the repository.

Answer (score 76):

This can (thankfully) be easily solved by modifying the .gitmodules file on-the-fly on Travis, so that the SSH URL is replaced with the public URL, before initializing submodules. To accomplish this, add the following to .travis.yml:

```
# Handle git submodules yourself
git:
    submodules: false
# Use sed to replace the SSH URL with the public URL, then initialize submodules
before_install:
    - sed -i 's/git@github.com:/https:\/\/github.com\//' .gitmodules
    - git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Thanks to Michael Iedema for his [gist](https://gist.github.com/iedemam/9830045) from which I derived this solution.

If your submodules are private repositories, it should work to include credentials in the https URLs, I recommend making a [GitHub access token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use) with restricted permissions for this purpose:

```
# Replace <user> and <token> with your GitHub username and access token respectively
- sed -i 's/git@github.com:/https:\/\/<user>:<token>@github.com\//' .gitmodules
```

Comment: This is by far the best solution to this problem so far!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for private repositories. All of these private repositories are under the same github account, and turned on for travis. Anyone has a clue? Thanks.

Comment: @inder I haven't tried Travis with private repositories yet, but you'll need some way to give access to your repositories. It's kind of a problem in itself.

Comment: @inder Can you access your private repositories by combining HTTPS with user/password, i.e., `https://user:password@github.com/organization/repo.git`? If so, you can modify the sed command correspondingly. Let me know if this works for you. See [Travis Pro documentation](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/travis-pro/) for reference.

Comment: @aknuds Yes, Travis Pro documentation works. I created a build user on GitHub and added its ssh keys as suggested in the link. Also, DELETE the submodule hack suggested above. Thanks.

Comment: If you're on a Mac OS X system and you're wondering why sed fails, it's due macs specific sed version which required the -e option after the -i option.

Comment: I prefer to use another delimiter than `/` when replacing in URLs etc. `sed -i 's|git@github.com:|https://github.com/|' .gitmodules`

Comment: I agree this is a great solution, you can see the screenshot of it in action here https://twitter.com/DinisCruz/status/729580391686934528

Comment: @carlin.scott I wonder if Travis has changed its behaviour then. I would check with them.

Answer (score 24):

I'd recommend using the `https` scheme for submodules, as that'll allow you to pull on Travis and push locally: `https://github.com/quadroid/clonejs.git`.

Comment: Travis adding `/` at the end of path and says that repo isn't exists >_<

Answer (score 12):

Travis now supports accessing submodule using ssh, which is by far the easiest solution. You only need to associate your ssh key (or the ssh key of a dedicated CI user) with the Github project you are building, as described in the [documentation for private dependencies](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/private-dependencies/).

`$ travis sshkey --upload ~/.ssh/id_rsa -r myorg/main`

Note that Travis recommends creating a dedicated user so that you do not have to use your own ssh key.

Comment: To make this explanation even more complete; find a user with access to both the repository Travis is building and that of the submodule (Travis recommends creating a specific CI user for this), and then run this command *for the repo doing the build*.

Comment: It's not available on travis.org (only travis.com, not free)

Comment: This doesn't really improve security does it... having your github key spread around..

Comment: @matt I updated my answer to indicate that Travis recommends using a dedicated CI user for this - which I think is a good idea for several reasons.

Answer (score 7):

You get this error because you specified your submodules via ssh-urls. For ssh access from the travis-ci environment you need to [configure a key](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/private-dependencies/).

Alternatively, you can just use relative URLs for your git submodules since you project and your submodules are all available on Github.

Git resolves relative urls against the `ORIGIN`.

Example:

Using the first 2 entries from your `.gitmodules`:

```
[submodule "lib/es5-shim"]
        path = lib/es5-shim
        url = git@github.com:kriskowal/es5-shim.git
[submodule "build/html"]
        path = build/html
        url = git@github.com:quadroid/clonejs.git
```

Replaced with relative URLs:

```
[submodule "lib/es5-shim"]
        path = lib/es5-shim
        url = ../../kriskowal/es5-shim.git
[submodule "build/html"]
        path = build/html
        url = ../clonejs.git
```

Then when cloning - say - via https the origin is set like this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/quadroid/clonejs.git
$ cd clonejs
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/quadroid/clonejs.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/quadroid/clonejs.git (push)
```

When cloning via ssh:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:quadroid/clonejs.git
$ cd clonejs
$ git remote -v                                
origin  git@github.com:quadroid/clonejs.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:quadroid/clonejs.git (push)
```

With relative urls, the usual submodule sequence works independently of the origin:

```
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update
```

Comment: The relative URL's work very well in my case, and that is possibly the most elegant solution for public repos. Thanks for coming up with this technique!

Comment: Annoyingly however, it seems to break github's automatic hyperlinking to the submodules github page.

Comment: This doesn't work for private submodules. It seems that travis hides the fact that it's using a private token to access the repo but it doesn't do this when cloning submodules.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just directly manipulate your .gitmodules file via `git`. (Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30675130/4068264)).

```
git config --file=.gitmodules submodule.SUBMODULE_PATH.url https://github.com/ORG/REPO.git
```

Answer (score 1):

**Actual on 2022**:

1. Go to the repo settings in travis-ci and enable `Clone or Import` option for repos which used as submodule
   [image: Clone or Import]

2. Use `https` protocol in your `.gitmodules` (but better to use relative paths without a protocol)
3. Enjoy. I spent only 3 hours to figure it out