# git remote submodule url doesn't apply to local git repository

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git repository that has a submodule with a url that points to a local directory on the machine. (The directory is actually inside the directory of the git repository, but should be maintained as a separate project.) This works well until I clone that repository to a remote machine. The submodule keeps the url that is local to that remote repository—it doesn't exist on the cloned repository.

Is there some way to make this work? Or, should I just remove the submodule and keep track of it separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a submodule you should use a remote repository. For example (see [here](http://chrisjean.com/2009/04/20/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/)):

> git submodule add git@mygithost:billboard lib/billboard

So now what you have to do is:

1) clone your submodule to the remote repository,

2) change your local submodule references to the new remote location.

You can see  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913701/changing-remote-repository-for-a-git-submodule) how to do that.

Comment: Yep that was it. I added `ssh://server` to my url and that made it work. Thanks!