# git submodule in superproject has later commits not seen in submodule itself

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a super-module "Research" that includes a submodule "Simulator".

When I clone Simulator repository, and do git log, I get this

```
~/Simulator$ git log
commit abcd...
Date: Feb 1.......
........
```

When I clone Research repository, and do git submodule update --init and do git log inside Research/Simulator, I get this

```
~/Research/Simulator$ git log
commit efgh...
Date: Feb 2.......
........
```

So, by cloning Research repo and pulling submodule, I get newer version of Simulator, compared to just cloning Simulator repo directly...

I have another problem that I think is caused by this.

I had to move git repos to New Server, and when I test cloning Research and pull submodules from the repo in the New Server, I get this,

```
~/Research_test$ git submodule update
Cloning into Simulator...
....
fatal: reference is not a tree: efgh...
Unable to checkout 'efgh...' in submodule path 'Simulator'
```

The funny thing is that when I clone Research and pull submodules from Old Server, it pulls Simulator successfully. (well, with some weirdness like I explained before)

I migrated repo by simply copying the repository (bare) directories

My goal is

1. when I clone Simulator directly, it should pull the latest version....
2. that "reference is not a tree" error should go away......

Btw, working directory for Simualtor has been deleted, so I only have the repo to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> by cloning Research repo and pulling submodule, I get newer version of Simulator, compared to just cloning Simulator repo directly...

It is possible that the submodule is set to display a commit done on a branch different from the default one.

- cloning directly the repo clone the master branch (commit `abcd`)
- cloning it through a submodule clone a fixed SHA1 doe on a branch from master (commit `efgh`)

> when I clone Simulator directly, it should pull the latest version

As mentioned in "[git submodule tracking latest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189575/git-submodule-tracking-latest/9189815#9189815)", git 1.8.2 allows you to define a submodule tracking the latest of a given branch.

> that "reference is not a tree" error should go away.

Check the `.gitmodules` file of the bare '`Research`' repo that you moved.
Chances are it is still reference the old server as the url for the submodule.
[Change it to the url of the new server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914090/6309).