# Tell git to ignore my RSA public key

Tags: git, bitbucket, public-key-encryption

I have added a new public key to log into my server.

git is attempting to use the same key for bitbucket, this fails and git cannot be used as its trying to use that public key.

Is there a config option for git to tell it to ignore the public key i have in place?

I have attempted to set up multiple ssh identities, by using this https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=271943168 but its failed and git still does not work.

Rather than set up a whole new key, I just want git to ignore the key altogether.

**Edit**

My current ssh config looks like this

```
ServerAliveInterval 15
ServerAliveCountMax 3

Host bitbucket
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket
```

Comment: I do this all the time.  It's less of a git setting and more of an SSH one.  What does your SSH config look like?

Comment: I have added this to my question jszakmeister

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I imagine the problem is the url to your repo.  It needs to be adjusted to use the alias created in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket:path/to/repo.git
```

Additionally, you could make your `~/.ssh/config` look like this:

```
ServerAliveInterval 15
ServerAliveCountMax 3

Host bitbucket
 HostName bitbucket.org
 User git
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/bitbucket
```

Note the presence of the `User` key.  That will tell ssh that whenever you use the alias `bitbucket` to also use the user name `git`.  The above command can then become:

```
git remote set-url origin bitbucket:path/to/repo.git
```

Additionally, whenever you clone, you can do:

```
git clone bitbucket:path/to/repo.git
```

To also save you a little typing.

Comment: A clone worked right away. I edited the config file manually though and an existing project still failed. I then used `git remote set-url` and it worked. Another project failed too, but this had a submodule. This helped me with that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913701/changing-remote-repository-for-a-git-submodule - all working now :-)

Comment: Interesting... editing the `.git/config` should have worked.  Perhaps something wasn't quite right there in your edit.  At any rate, I'm glad it worked for you!

Comment: I think it might have been because I left in `ssh://`