# How to change a connection to GitHub from SSH to HTTPS?

Tags: git, github, ssh, https, git-remote

I created my first repository in GitHub yesterday. When making the connection I used SSH instead of HTTPS, so I went through a little painful SSH key creation and connection process. At some point I got stuck and the connection failed. I wondered at that moment how I could revert the process I started and begin with a HTTPS connection instead. Happily, today I got the connection working through SSH but I'm wondering about the value of being able to change the type of connection (SSH vs HTTPS) and if there is a way to do it.

Comment: If you want to `git push` local modifications to [github](http://github.com/), you'll better keep the *ssh* connection. Read some ssh tutorial, and configure the private & public keys to avoid typing your password more than once.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, both SSH and HTTPS connections can be used to `push` to GitHub (and many other hosts).

Comment: Instead of `git remote set-url` I typically text-edit the `.git/config` file. You just need to observe different url structure for both on some repo servers.

Comment: I often use https as fetch url and ssh as Push url, the advantage is that I don’t need to unlock my ssh key for random fetches.

Comment: After reading answers, if you want to change the connection of a submodule: [How to change the remote repository for a git submodule?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/913701)

Answer (score 163, accepted):

Assuming your remote is called `origin`, run

- `git remote set-url origin https://...`
- `git remote set-url --push origin https://...`

You can view the configured remotes with `git remote -v`, which should now show your updated URLs.

See [the documentation for `git-remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) for more details.

Comment: The elided `...` make this somewhat difficult to understand. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71096006/6243352) seems clearer: we're removing the `git@github.com:` prefix and replacing it with the `https://github.com/` prefix, keeping the `<Username>/<RepoName>` postfix (which should be the same URL as from the green clone code button on the GitHub repo).

Answer (score 20):

here are some aliases (oneliners) to switch your repo from ssh to https and back. Assuming your default remote is named `origin` and your remote is github.com

```
alias git-https="git remote set-url origin https://github.com/$(git remote get-url origin | sed 's/https:\/\/github.com\///' | sed 's/git@github.com://')"
alias git-ssh="  git remote set-url origin git@github.com:$(    git remote get-url origin | sed 's/https:\/\/github.com\///' | sed 's/git@github.com://')"
```

they're a bit longer than necessary to make them idempotent

Comment: Thanks for that. Here's a version that works for non-github.com and URLs that have, or don't have, a leading `/` in their path: `git remote set-url origin $(git remote get-url origin | sed 's/^git@\(.*\):\/*\(.*\).git/https:\/\/\1\/\2.git/')`

Comment: ..and the reverse of @TimBunce's version: `git remote set-url origin $(git remote get-url origin | sed 's/^https:\/\/\([^\/]*\)\/\(.*\).git/git@\1\:\2.git/')` (assuming the result should NOT have a leading `/` in its path).

Comment: For AWS code commit URLs (e.g. `https://git-codecommit.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/somerepo`), you can just switch the https: and ssh: `git remote set-url origin $(git remote get-url origin | sed 's/^ssh:/https:/')` or to switch to SSH `git remote set-url origin $(git remote get-url origin | sed 's/^https:/ssh:/')`

Answer (score 6):

So guys I struggled with this problem for a while but finally got how to solve it.
First make sure you have updated your git to the latest version using:

`C:\> git update-git-for-windows`

Afterwards run the command:

`C:\>git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:`

Then:

`C:\>git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://`

If you still get the Permission denied (publickey) error you can do the process manually as follows:

Navigate to your .gitconfig file.

You can check for its location using:

`git config --list --show-origin`

Open the file using notepad.

**Delete this section:**

```
[url "git://"]
    insteadOf = https://
[url "insteadOf = git@github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

**Replace with:**

```
[url "https://"]
    insteadOf = git://
[url "https://github.com/"]
    insteadOf = git@github.com:
```

After this you should be able to log in using your Personal Access token successfully.

Answer (score 4):

Put these alias definitions in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias git-ssh='git remote set-url origin "$(git remote get-url origin | sed -E '\''s,^https://([^/]*)/(.*)$,git@\1:\2,'\'')"'

alias git-https='git remote set-url origin "$(git remote get-url origin | sed -E '\''s,^git@([^:]*):/*(.*)$,https://\1/\2,'\'')"'
```

Then,

- to switch from `https` to `ssh`: `git-ssh`
- to switch from `ssh` to `https`: `git-https`

Successfully tested with both *github.com* and *gitlab.com* repos.

Note: I used `-E` for extended regular expression, and I used comma, instead of the usual slash, to separate the parts of the substitution operation. Together, these helped reduce [leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).

Answer (score 3):

```
  git remote -v
# View existing remotes
# origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (fetch)
# origin  https://github.com/user/repo.git (push)

    git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user/repo2.git

# Change the 'origin' remote's URL

    git remote -v

# Verify new remote URL
# origin  https://github.com/user/repo2.git (fetch)
# origin  https://github.com/user/repo2.git (push)
```