# Use ssh to git pull from EC2

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

Might be an odd case as I initially cloned a repo using https inside EC2.
Now I have setup ssh for the EC2 instance to connect to github (creating a ssh key pair inside EC2 and added the public key to github). I have tested the ssh connection and it works as I can clone repos from my github account inside the EC2 instance.

But how to use ssh to do `git pull` from the repo that I initially cloned using https? For this repo, if I do `git pull` it still uses https asking for my username and an access token.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change a connection to GitHub from SSH to HTTPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30683399/how-to-change-a-connection-to-github-from-ssh-to-https). I realize that you want to do the opposite, but I think the basic procedure is the same either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
cd <your-git-directory>
git remote set-url origin <git-ssh-url>
```

Article on this [here](https://pandammonium.org/how-to-change-a-git-repository-from-https-to-ssh/)