# Mirroring git repository with submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, mirror

Suppose that I have a git server with several repos, and that one of the repos includes some of the others as submodules.  Is it possible to mirror all of the repositories on another server and redirect the submodule dependencies without altering the history?

Answer (score -1):

> redirect the submodule dependencies without altering the history?

If that involves changing the remote repo of a submodule within a parent repo, then the history of that parent repo will have to change, with one new commit:
It would need to record the modification in the `.gitmodules` file, as described in "[Changing remote repository for a git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914090/6309)".