# Azure github deployment with private submodule

Tags: git, azure, github, git-submodules

I am trying to deploy private repository with github onto Azure and it used to work perfectly until I made a piece of repository into separate private submodule that is also hosted on github.

Now, every time I try to deploy to Azure it breaks during submodule deployment with following message:
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com'

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: I get the something similar in my activity log on Azure: Cloning into 'project'...
bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Invalid argument
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/username/submodule.git' into submodule path 'submodule' failed

D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe submodule update --init --recursive

Answer (score 0):

As in [this issue](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-git/issues/176) (or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6565661/6309)), check the remote url of your main repo, and of your submodule

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote -v
cd path/to/submodule
git remote -v
```

You could [switch the url of the submodule to an ssh one instead of an https](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30675130/6309), add, commit and push the parent repo (to record the change), and then deploy again.

Comment: Same problem.. Now I get ERROR: Repository not found.fatal: Could not read from remote repository.Please make sure you have the correct access rightsand the repository exists.Clone of 'git@github.com:username/repo.git'