# How can I add a file to a git submodule?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I want to make a Python package out of a repository that I've added as a submodule to my repository. Is there a way to add a `__init__.py` file to this submodule and to track it in the parent repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add any file in that submodule repo, you will have to:

- add, commit and push from that submodule repo (assuming you have the right to push to its upstream repo. If not, you need to [change the remote url of that submodule by one representing a fork that you own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30675130/6309))
- go back to the parent repo, add, commit and push: the parent repo will tack the new submodule SHA1 (new state of its tree). That SHA1 is called the **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)** (a [special entry in the parent repo index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309))