# How can I share local commits to my TFS 2017 server from a submodule hosted in github?

Tags: git, github, tfs

There's a github project that I've added to my TFS repo as a submodule.  I've made a few commits to the submodule/github project that have not yet been accepted into the public github project.  How do I get those local commits off my machine to somewhere TFS can access them so TFS can build my entire project (including the modified submodule)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could:

- create an Git empty repo in your TFS server,
- change the submodule url from the GitHub one to your new local repo
  See "[Changing remote repository for a git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30675130/6309)"
- push your local commits to that new repo
- add/commit and push in your parent project (where you changed the submodule repo url)

Comment: That's the exact solution I got working yesterday, so I guess I did it right! :)  Thanks for posting the answer, hopefully this helps someone else in the same predicament.