# Git: different origin for submodule in different branch

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-remote

My project contains a submodule `submodA`. For the `branch_dev` the origin url of the submodule links to `sub_dev` which is a fork of `sub_master` but where I can apply modification and commit. For the `branch_master` the origin url of the submodule links direclty to `sub_master`

`branch_dev`/`submodA`--origin-> `sub_dev` --fork--> `sub_master`

`master_dev`/`submodA`--origin-> `sub_master`

By doing like this, I can clone `branch_dev` and find automatically the modification I did in `sub_dev` using `git submodule update --init --recursive`.

My problem is that the origin url of `submodA` which is different between my two branches doesn't change automatically and I have to change manually in the submodule the origin url with `git remote set-url origin sub_dev` or `sub_master`.

Does it have a solution to automatically change the origin url of my submodule when switching between branches ? I may try something too complicated so I would also be glad to here others solutions for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you don't need to change origin's URL at all. Add two different remotes (one of them can be called `origin` but that doesn't matter) and set different upstreams to every branch. Something like this:

```
cd submodA
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin master
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin2 dev
```

Now you can `git push/pull` in the submodule without explicitly naming remote, so git uses the upstream of the currently checked out branch.

Comment: Thank you for answering. In `submodA` I only have one branch `master` which has two different remotes according to the branch of the project I chose. If I create two branches in `submodA` I guess I would need to checkout the branch I want to use every time I switch between `master_dev` and `branch_dev` ?

My goal would be to have only one branch in `submodA` which fetch the good remote `sub_dev` or `sub_master` according two the branch projet. Like this, people who clone my repo will automatically have the appropriate submodule by running `git submodule update --init --recursive`

Comment: I finally found what I was looking for [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913701/changing-remote-repository-for-a-git-submodule). I had already modified the .gitmodules file but the command `git sync` was the missing piece of the puzzle