# Is it possible to set git remote url to a sub folder in the repository?

Tags: git, github

For a repo (say "test"), that has the folder structure as

├── Project1
├── Project2
├── Project3

Can I set a remote url for just project1 ?

Comment: Per-folder Git remotes don't make any sense. It looks like you're cramming multiple projects into a single repository. Git is designed to support one project per repository, and following that convention will simplify things for you.

Comment: This is doable if you can set up each of your projects as git submodules. See this answer for steps  - https://stackoverflow.com/a/914090/866021

Comment: @Chris This projects are very small and I don't want to create repo for each one of them. Those are basically codes for all my college classes.

Comment: @Aditya, then you'll have to deal with the implications of that. Single-project repositories are almost always the better choice (though of course there are exceptions like Google's famous monorepo).

Answer (score 4):

No and yes.  That is, you can *set* this, but it will not do what you want, whatever that may be.

A *remote* is just a short name that acts as a key:

- `origin` => `remote.origin.url`, `remote.origin.fetch`
- `xyz` => `remote.xyz.url`, `remote.xyz.fetch`

and so on.  You can set the *url* for each such key to anything you like: `https://example.com/path/to/repo` or `/local/path` or `jellybeans` or whatever you like, but the things that *use* this value are `git fetch`, `git push`, and `git ls-remote`.  These all contact another Git repository at the given URL and transfer *commits* (not files) back and forth, or in the case of `git ls-remote`, tell you what commits and branch names are available.

Since `git fetch` and `git push` transfer *entire commits*, files come along with the commits for the ride, but they have the names you gave them *in the commits*.

You can, however, make commits that contain *only* files in `Project1`.  Checking out such a commit will *remove* all the `Project2` and `Project3` files, and then checking out a commit that has all the files will *bring back* all the `Project2` and `Project3` files.  But when you run `git push` or `git fetch`, you're likely to send and receive commits that contain *all* the files along with any commits that contain *only* the `Project1` files, so that's probably not a great idea.

If you store each project in a separate Git repository, that will probably get you what you want.  Although I generally recommend avoiding submodules, you can make each of these repositories a submodule of a single *superproject* that does nothing but coordinate all the submodules; this particular path is workable.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do a remote repository for your Project 1, I think you would need to start out by setting it up as a separate repository locally.  As torek points out, in git the "remote" maps to a "repo"--you can manage your commits to include only updates to the Project 1 directory, but that's not really a separate remote.

If you set up the Project 1 directory as a separate git repository, you can add a remote to it.  To get it into your directory tree, you can:
a.)  use symlinks in your main project tree to point to the Project 1 directory;
b.)  add it to your main project as a submodule.

You can get more info on submodules in the docs or in [Mastering Git Submodules.](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-submodules-34c65e940407)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can. Use GitHub's submodules: https://blog.github.com/2016-02-01-working-with-submodules/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clone a subdirectory, [this StackOVerflow question / answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/600189/6597679) says "no".

If you are looking for commiting in a subdirectory, then the answer is yes.

1. Make changes to the subdirectory
2. Then execute the following command to see which changes have been done:

   git status
3. You will see the changes you made, for example:

   modified:   application/Email.php
   modified:   application/Config.php
4. to add the changes, do this at the command line:

   git add application/*
5. Commit your changes as follows:

   git commit -m "Add email suport to application"
6. When you work on [GitHub](https://github.com), [GitLab](https://gitlab.com) or a similar platform, push your changes to the remote repository:

   git push origin master

For the last step, I assume that you have configured Git well and that you know how things work. Otherwise, use [this tutorial](https://product.hubspot.com/blog/git-and-github-tutorial-for-beginners) to get started.