# Pushing Files to a particular directory of a Github Repository using Git Bash/Terminal

Tags: git, github, repository, push, commit

I have an existing repository in Github. But how do I commit changes and push the files to a particular directory in that repository?

Note - I've done all the steps from `git remote add origin` to 'git commit' to 'git push` but, how do I select that particular directory I want to push changes into the repository from the terminal.

PS - I want to push changes from my local [which is not in my project directory] **to a particular existing Directory of the Repository**.

Comment: The question seems unclear. You would have a local copy of the repository containing all the directories in the remote repository. Just place your files there.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Suppose I've created some files in a `temp` local directory [which is not in my project directory for some reasons]  and I wanna push the files inside the `temp` folder to a pre-existing directory of my repository using `git remote add`. I'm facing my problems there. Hope you get my point.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50451684/5987698) may help.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose I've created some files in a temp local directory [which is not in my project directory for some reasons] and I wanna push the files inside the temp folder to a pre-existing directory of my repository using git remote add. I

First, [`git remote add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emaddem) is just to declare a remote URL: it does not add or push any file.

Second, simply copy those file in the local repository, with the right folder.
Then:

```
git add theRightFolder
git commit -m "Add theRightFolder content"
git push -u origin master
```

If that folder includes other files you do not want to push, you will need to git add only the files you have copied

```
git add theRightFolder/file1
...
git add theRightFolder/filen

git commit -m "Add some files in theRightFolder"
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the same.