# Clone a repository from Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, netbeans-8

I'm using NetBeans 8.2 on Windows 10 trying to clone a repo from BitBucket.
Here are the steps I've done:

1. Go to Team > Git > Clone...
2. Copied the project URL to the Repository URL field: https://bitbucket.org/thiagomp/linkcheckr/src/master/
   I've also tried https://bitbucket.org/thiagomp/linkcheckr.git
3. Created an App Password on BitBucket
4. Inserted the User and Password according to the password generated by BitBucket on step #3
5. Click on Next button to get the "Incorrect credentials for the repository at https://bitbucket.org/thiagomp/linkcheckr/src/master/"

Here is a screenshot of the Netbeans configuration
[image: screenshot for the NetBeans configuration]

Would you please help me with the correct way to input the BitBucket credentials on NetBeans 8.2? Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following url:

```
https://username@bitbucket.org/repo-address.git
```

In your case, it would be:

```
https://ckr-thiagomp@bitbucket.org/thiagomp/linkcheckr.git
```

You would then need to enter the password (make sure it is the correct one).

Comment: Thanks for your help Nasir!
Interesting is that, whenever I type that, NetBeans already re-format the URL to `https://bitbucket.org/thiagomp/linkcheckr.git`. It places the username to the _User_ field. I'm pretty sure about the password. I'm using the same generated by BitBucket.

Comment: Try changing the password. Some time it helps.

Comment: In this case, I can't change the password, but I did create another App Password to make sure I was informing the correct password. Nice to notice that I'm granting all permissions possible for the user.

Comment: I just tried the above again and it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks Nasir, not sure why it's not working for me. Interesting to note that I'm able to work on the terminal, via git bash.

Answer (score 0):

First, I confirm the proper URL is `https://bitbucket.org/thiagomp/linkcheckr.git`

Second, check if you have activated [2FA on BitBucket for your account](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/two-step-verification-777023203.html).

Third, if you can try and [switch to an SSH URL](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html), to see if you can access the repo that way.

```
git@bitbucket.org:thiagomp/linkcheckr.git
```

---

Note the error is:

```
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.git]: https://lckr-thiagomp@bitbucket.org/thiagomp/linkcheckr/src/master/: not authorized
```

Check your `.gitmodules` file: if it includes the URL https://lckr-thiagomp@bitbucket.org/thiagomp/linkcheckr/src/master/, then it is not a valid https URL for a Git repository.
The valid one would be:

```
https://lckr-thiagomp@bitbucket.org/thiagomp/linkcheckr.git
```

So [change its URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914090/6309) and see if this work better.

Comment: Thanks for your help VonC. I don't have 2FA enabled. I've tried the SSH URL and it's nice that it enabled some other options on Netbeans like adding my authorized public key, but not even that worked.
Meanwhile, I'll keep on using Git Bash, but Netbeans would be more convenient to use I think.

Comment: @ThiagoMelo OK. Is there any log file that could include some clues? (`%APPDATA%\NetBeans\*` or `%UserProfile%\.nbi\log\*.log`)

Comment: I've found a log on `%APPDATA%\NetBeans\8.2\var\log` directory and pasted the result here [link](https://pastebin.com/nc7WjE4R)

Comment: interesting that I can't find the .gitmodules file. Even searching the whole drive, I couldn't find it. Worth to mention that I've enabled hidden files to be visible

Comment: @ThiagoMelo THen check in your local repo/.git/modules files for any files with that string.