# Copy gitlab repo to Bitbucket including submodules

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket

I have a private repo in Gitlab and I would like to make its copy in bitbucket. I tried using `Import a Repository` feature and it works fine. It however clones the parent project and not the submodules. I see the reference to the submodules in the imported parent project.
[image]

How do I clone the submodules?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You should:

- either keep those references unchanges, and clone your new imported repo with the [`--recurse-submodule` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---recurse-submodulesltpathspec):

  ```
  git clone --recurse-submodules
  ```

That will work if those submodules reference public repos themselves.

- or you should repeat your import process for each private submodule, and then [update the `.gitmodules` URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30675130/6309) of your first imported repo.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in Bitbucket? Bitbucket doesnt have a CLI to run these commands.

Comment: @ArchitArora Once you have modified the submodule URL, all you need to do is push back the modified .gitmodules. Anyone else cloning that new repo would get the new submodules