# Cannot change/push .gitmodules file

Tags: git, git-submodules

I create a repo "main", containing a submodule "sub0", containing a submodule "sub1":

```
mkdir sub0 && cd sub0 && git init && touch README.md && git add README.md && git commit -am "Initial" && cd ..
mkdir sub1 && cd sub1 && git init && git submodule add ../sub0 sub0 && git commit -am "Initial" && cd ..
mkdir main && cd main && git init && git submodule add ../sub1 sub1 && git commit -am "Initial" && cd ..
```

I also tried

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

in `main`, but it makes not difference for the following issue.

Now, I got to `main/sub1/`, and make a change to the submodule configuration:

```
git config submodule.sub0.update none
```

For some strange reason, this change ends up in `../.git/modules/sub1/config` instead of in `.gitmodules`. Now, how do I push this change? git shows me no modified files in any of the repos.

Comment: `git config` changes config, why do you expect it to change `.gitmodules`? Use `git config --file=.gitmodules`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30675130/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+edit+%22.gitmodules%22

Comment: @phd thanks for explaining, that solved my problem.