# Update submodules for a Git repo cloned from local source

Tags: git, git-submodules

I've been trying to render a project from a template made with Copier, which contains a submodule `converter`, but faced a following issue:

```
Submodule 'converter' (/template_path/converter.git) registered for path 'converter'
fatal: repository '/template_path/converter.git' does not exist
fatal: clone of '/template_path/converter.git' into submodule path '/tmp/copier.vcs.clone.4y5n3ykb/converter' failed
```

where `/template_path/` denotes a path to the local repository with template.

I've reproduced this by cloning a local version of repository with template into another local directory and updating submodules with following command:

`git submodule update --checkout --init --recursive --force`,
which is exactly what is being called by Copier.

Both `.gitmodules` files in the original and cloned repos contain following path and url:

```
[submodule "converter"]
    path = converter
    url = ../converter.git
```

`Config` file in the original local repo contains valid url to the remote repository of `converter` submodule, but in the cloned one it has local path `/template_path/converter.git`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

An `url = ../converter.git` would mean a [bare repository](https://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/) `converter.git` cloned alongside your current project repository.

If you don't have that repository (bare) cloned locally, then you would need to update the submodule repository URL ([using `git submodule set-url`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914135/6309)) in order to reference an external (non-local) repository (from GitHub, GitLab or any other public repository hosting service).